# Rear hatch on 2021 Grand Cherokee only partly opens then closes

Tags: jeep, electronics, grand-cherokee, hatch

I have a 2021 Grand Cherokee purchased new (approaching 3 yrs ago). An odd problem started occurring a couple of months ago. When I trigger the rear hatch it opens maybe 8-12 inches then stops and closes again. If I trigger it again, it opens all the way just fine. In as little as 10-15 minutes, it will misbehave again. For example, I open the hatch at the grocery store... it misbehaves so I have to trigger it a second time. When I get home (about 10-15 minute drive), the hatch misbehaves again. I can use either the exterior handle, the button on the ceiling console, or the remote and get the same behavior. The struts hold the hatch open no problem, and in "manual" mode, the hatch seems to move freely throughout its range, so it seems unlikely that the motor is overloaded - besides, it operates normally immediately after each "problem" cycle.

The service department where I bought it has checked it out; they had the car for a day and only saw the problem occur once; they found that the battery was less than fully charged and considered it to be a possible cause; they charged and tested the battery, finding it to be in good condition. They found no faults reported by the body controller and did a recalibration (not clear of exactly what). From their point of view, they found nothing wrong, but I am still seeing the problem occur.

I have had annual rust protection applied twice - the most recent application seems to coincide with the initial appearance of this problem, making me wonder about a connection - possible contamination of a sensor or something.

I know nothing about the mechanical, electrical, electronic, or body control logic design of the hatch, so I couldn't begin to think of what could cause the observed behavior. I'm also not that inclined to do any troubleshooting or repair myself (especially since the car is still under warranty). Can anyone offer any insight so that I can get this problem resolved - perhaps give the service folks some useful guidance?

Comment: Video this problem with time and date stamp. Be sure video device is not shaking; use a rest like a tripod, magnetic mount on another vehicle, fixed mount, etc, to record the entire sequence for proof of recurrence for warranty repairs. Record several with different time/date stamps. Present a copy to your dealer and if necessary, another copy to regional or headquarters - customer support as evidence if your dealer denies the problem exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think they are denying the existence of the problem, just unable to reproduce it. It hadn't occurred to me to document the problem - something I will definitely do. Still looking for insight to possible causes though.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the struts hold the hatch open, the gas cylinders may have lost a little pressure in the three years since they were installed and may not be helping as much as the hatch lift controller expects. So here's an experiment.

The next ten times that you have to open the hatch, stand near the hatch, use the remote and gently help the hatch lift with a hand assist. Don't overdo it, just help it along. If these ten lifts proceed without any reversal, it's a pretty strong indicator that the struts are not providing as much lift as needed, and the dealer should replace them.

Let us know!